# launching a new activity from an ImageButton

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a new activity in my android app and I've got this code for it:

```
public void BSettings() {
    View.OnClickListener listSet = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    b.setOnClickListener(listSet);
}
```

Nevertheless, when clicking the button the app stops. The thing is that, when I only had the `toast`, it worked, so the problem may be the creation of the `intent` or the `startActivity(intent)`. What's wrong with these two lines?

In the logcat, this error appears:

```
07-20 13:44:10.714 1534-1547/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.android.systemui
PID: 1625
Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) }
Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
CPU usage from 12435ms to 0ms ago (2017-07-20 13:43:57.570 to 2017-07-20 13:44:10.004):
18% 1534/system_server: 13% user + 4.9% kernel / faults: 10451 minor 12 major
5.3% 1625/com.android.systemui: 4.1% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 5162 minor 8 major
4.5% 1890/adbd: 1.3% user + 3.1% kernel / faults: 587 minor
4.1% 1257/surfaceflinger: 0.4% user + 3.6% kernel / faults: 5 minor
3.1% 1731/com.android.phone: 2.4% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 1052 minor
1% 1296/zygote: 0.6% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 1635 minor
0.9% 1196/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
0.6% 1277/kworker/u3:0: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
0.8% 1256/servicemanager: 0.2% user + 0.5% kernel
0.3% 1297/audioserver: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel
0.2% 1306/netd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 922 minor
0.2% 1203/logd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 41 minor
0.2% 1279/dmcrypt_write: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
0.2% 1304/media.extractor: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 16 minor
0.1% 1305/mediaserver: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 163 minor
0.1% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0% 4/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
0.1% 1829/com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 126 minor
0% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0% kernel
0% 1254/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
0% 1284/kworker/u3:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
0% 1290/jbd2/dm-0-8: 0% user + 0% kernel
0% 1298/cameraserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 126 minor
0% 1744/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 37 minor
+0% 1899/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 1914/android.process.media: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 1930/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 1943/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 1949/com.android.printspooler: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 1971/com.android.launcher3: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 2005/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 2073/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 2084/com.google.android.partnersetup: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 2136/android.process.acore: 0% user + 0% kernel
+0% 2160/com.android.keychain: 0% user + 0% kernel
100% TOTAL: 61% user + 26% kernel + 10% iowait + 1.2% softirq
CPU usage from 54628ms to 54628ms ago (1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 to 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000) with 0% awake:
```

**EDIT**

After adding the activity to the manifest, it launche the activity, but after showing the new window, it stops. Tis is Settings code:

```
public class Settings extends Activity 
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.set);
    }
}
```

set code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/toolbar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeCloseDrawable"
        tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Configuración"
            android:layout_width="384dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.48"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/AutoLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="77dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="@string/titulo1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/autoarranuqe"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/interruptor"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/interruptor"
                android:text="@string/text1"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/int"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                tools:checked="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/WIFILayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="77dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="@string/t2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Wifi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText16"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:text="@string/texto2"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/PlayerIDLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="103dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.13">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/playerID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gr"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="@string/texto3"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorTertiary"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:inputType="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="@string/t3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText17"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:text="@string/bot1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/br"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gr"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gr"
                android:layout_below="@+id/gr"
                android:text="@string/bot2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ILayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.57">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:weightSum="1"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/t0"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/Fra "
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="54dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    tools:text="@string/tex" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/En"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:checked="true"
                    tools:text="@string/texto5"
                    android:layout_weight="0.17" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/Es"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.41"
                    android:checked="true"
                    tools:text="@string/text4" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: add the logcat please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to launch a new activity from imagebutton but my app stops working in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609939/trying-to-launch-a-new-activity-from-imagebutton-but-my-app-stops-working-in-emu)

Comment: By the way you should change your BSettings method to bSettings. Methods are supposed to be camelcase

Answer (score 0):

Is `Settings` a declared activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? If you try to start an `Activity` that is not declared in the manifest, your app will crash.

Comment: You were right, I had two versions and forgot adding it in this one. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You should add Settings Activity to the AndroidManifest.xml like this code :

```
<activity
            android:name=".Settings"/>
```